# Inner Join returning no results

Tags: mysql

I need to get rows out from article and users table when the slug appears in my highlight table.

```
Highlight Table

id | slug
 1   blue
 2   green

Article Table

id | slug | title
1    blue
2    pink

User Table

id | slug | name
1    blue
2    green
3    brown
```

Heres my query:

```
SELECT slug from highlight_table
INNER JOIN article_table ON highlight_table.slug = article_table.slug
INNER JOIN user_table ON highlight_table.slug = user_table.slug
```

I would hope to get id 1 from article table and id 1 and 2 from users table.

The issue is Im getting nothing back from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query has an error because your `SELECT slug` is ambiguous. Your column `slug` appears in all of your tables so MySQL doesn't know which column to return. You need to do

```
SELECT `highlight_table`.`slug` from `highlight_table`
```

This will tell MySQL to only return the `slug` column from the `highlight_table`.

You should then only get 1 row which is blue, because blue exists in all three tables. Changing to `LEFT JOIN` for both article and user tables would get you 2 results back (green and blue) as `INNER JOIN` basically works as an AND and `LEFT JOIN` works more like an OR

**Update!**

Based on the final lot of information here is a query that does work:

```
SELECT highlight.slug from highlight
    LEFT JOIN article ON highlight.slug = article.slug
    LEFT JOIN user ON highlight.slug = user.slug
WHERE
    article.slug IS NOT NULL OR user.slug IS NOT NULL
```

Another example of doing this:

```
SELECT `highlight`.`slug` from `highlight`
WHERE `highlight`.`slug` IN (SELECT `user`.`slug` FROM `user` UNION SELECT `article`.`slug` FROM `article`)
```

OR

```
SELECT `highlight`.`slug` from `highlight`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `user`.`slug` FROM `user` UNION SELECT `article`.`slug` FROM `article`) AS `allslugs` ON `highlight`.`slug` = `allslugs`.`slug`
```

Another update, I call this one "fun with joins"

```
SELECT `highlight`.`slug` from `highlight`
    RIGHT JOIN `user` ON `highlight`.`slug` = `user`.`slug`
    LEFT JOIN `article` ON `highlight`.`slug` = `article`.`slug`
WHERE
    `highlight`.`slug` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Ive updated the ambitious select. I've also changed to LEFT JOIN, but this doesnt seem to work either, now Im getting all rows from my highlights table even though they are not in my other 2 tables.

Comment: Sounds like you have other issues you are not sharing. See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fa815/3) it only returns what we expected green and blue.

Comment: @Rahul is also on the right track, so if neither of our suggestions work then you need to give us more information about your data as it doesn't sound like it's as you've described.

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt work either, try putting in a value into the highlight table that isnt in either article or users table, the query will still return it.

Comment: Update uses superfulous where clause, Im sure this is possible with joins alone.

Comment: it does on the fiddle and it does on my local server. There where clause is necessary to filter out slugs from the hightlights which are not in either article or user. If you can find a way using just joins then please do let us know... the where clause is designed for this job so don't be afraid of things you do not understand.

Comment: Youve provided quite the set of answers, im just working through these, thanks!

Comment: LEFT JOIN article WHERE article ... IS NOT NULL is a rather contradictory (or tautologous) idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to qualify the column name in select list

```
SELECT h.`slug` from HighlightTable h
INNER JOIN ArticleTable a ON h.`slug` = a.`slug`
INNER JOIN UserTable u ON h.`slug` = u.`slug`;
```

Can't reproduce the issue. See [This Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bb7b4/1)

per your latest comment you need a `LEFT JOIN` query like

```
SELECT h.`slug` from HighlightTable h
LEFT JOIN ArticleTable a ON h.`slug` = a.`slug`
LEFT JOIN UserTable u ON h.`slug` = u.`slug`;
```

Then do a separate `JOIN` and `UNION` the result set

```
    SELECT h.`slug` from HighlightTable h
    INNER JOIN ArticleTable a ON h.`slug` = a.`slug`
   UNION
    SELECT h.`slug` from HighlightTable h
    INNER JOIN UserTable u ON h.`slug` = u.`slug`;
```

Comment: Im afraid this still gives no results

Comment: @panthro, see edit in answer specially the fiddle link

Comment: The fiddle does reproduce the issue. I want everything from the highlight table, if it appears in article table or users table. So in your fiddle, we should also have green returned.

Comment: @panthro, NO it shouldn't. Since *green* is not present in Article table and you are doing inner join. If you want green as well then consider doing a `left join` instead

Comment: Thats my question, R.Chappell has stated I need a left join, so im trying that, but that doesnt appear to be working either.

Comment: @panthro, see the edited query for left join ... did you tried the same?

Comment: Yes ive tried the left join, it returns everything from the highlight table even if it doesnt appear in the article or users table. I only want rows returned from highlight table if they appear in article OR users table.

Comment: @panthro, bit confused as not sure what's your actual intention here but see the final edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: Im afraid that doesnt help. The question is simple - select all rows from highlight where the row exists in either article or users