# Getting more than one field with a union select?

Tags: mysql

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728845/inner-join-returning-no-results)

I use the following to get all slugs from the highlight table that also exist in the user OR article table:

```
SELECT `highlight`.`slug` from `highlight`
WHERE `highlight`.`slug` IN (SELECT `user`.`slug` FROM `user`
UNION SELECT `article`.`slug` FROM `article`)
```

The issue now is that I also wish to select a title from both the article and user table. I've tried adding the column in the select, but it doesn't work.

How can I also pull out the title?

EDIT:

Highlight Table

```
id | slug
 1   blue
 2   green
```

Article Table

```
id | slug | title
1    blue BT
2    pink PT
```

User Table

```
id | slug | title
1    blue BT
2    green GT
3    brown BRT
```

You should get out, BT and GT as titles.

Comment: Could you please add some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head: I think you need to formulate the query the other way round—`SELECT` the `UNION` of the two tables and then `(INNER) JOIN` it on the highlight table:

```
SELECT
  a.slug, a.title
FROM
  (SELECT slug, title FROM user
   UNION 
   SELECT slug, title FROM article)
  ) AS a
INNER JOIN highlight
  ON a.slug = highlight.slug
```